# Issue with Child theme after updating theme - site broken

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I've got an issue with a Wordpress site I've built. I created a child theme, and have just updated the main theme, and the site is showing the white screen of death!

Is there an issue with the functions.php please? I suspect it's pretty obvious, but I'm nervous of trying any changes and creating further trouble!

Can anyone advise please?

Many thanks
K

```
<?php


define('MFN_THEME_VERSION', '26.4.0.8');

// theme related filters

add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');

add_filter('the_excerpt', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');

/**
 * White Label
 * IMPORTANT: We recommend the use of Child Theme to change this
 */

defined('WHITE_LABEL') or define('WHITE_LABEL', false);

/**
 * textdomain
 */

load_theme_textdomain('betheme', get_template_directory() .'/languages'); // frontend
load_theme_textdomain('mfn-opts', get_template_directory() .'/languages'); // admin panel

/**
 * theme options
 */

require_once(get_theme_file_path('/muffin-options/theme-options.php'));

/**
 * theme functions
 */

$theme_disable = mfn_opts_get('theme-disable');

require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/theme-functions.php'));
require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/theme-head.php'));

if ( is_admin() ) {
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/admin/class-mfn-api.php'));
}

// menu

require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/theme-menu.php'));
if (! isset($theme_disable['mega-menu'])) {
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/theme-mega-menu.php'));

}

// builder

require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/builder/class-mfn-builder.php'));

// post types

$post_types_disable = mfn_opts_get('post-type-disable');

require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/post-types/class-mfn-post-type.php'));

if (! isset($theme_disable['custom-icons'])) {
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/post-types/class-mfn-post-type-icons.php'));
}
if (! isset($post_types_disable['template'])) {
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/post-types/class-mfn-post-type-template.php'));
}
if (! isset($post_types_disable['client'])) {
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/post-types/class-mfn-post-type-client.php'));
}
if (! isset($post_types_disable['offer'])) {
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/post-types/class-mfn-post-type-offer.php'));
}
if (! isset($post_types_disable['portfolio'])) {
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/post-types/class-mfn-post-type-portfolio.php'));
}
if (! isset($post_types_disable['slide'])) {
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/post-types/class-mfn-post-type-slide.php'));
}
if (! isset($post_types_disable['testimonial'])) {
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/post-types/class-mfn-post-type-testimonial.php'));
}

if (! isset($post_types_disable['layout'])) {
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/post-types/class-mfn-post-type-layout.php'));
}

if(function_exists('is_woocommerce')){
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/post-types/class-mfn-post-type-product.php'));
}

require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/post-types/class-mfn-post-type-page.php'));
require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/post-types/class-mfn-post-type-post.php'));

// includes

require_once(get_theme_file_path('/includes/content-post.php'));
require_once(get_theme_file_path('/includes/content-portfolio.php'));

// shortcodes

require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/theme-shortcodes.php'));

// hooks

require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/theme-hooks.php'));

// sidebars

require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/theme-sidebars.php'));

// widgets

require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/widgets/class-mfn-widgets.php'));

// TinyMCE

require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/tinymce/tinymce.php'));

// plugins

require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/class-mfn-love.php'));
require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/plugins/visual-composer.php'));
require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/plugins/elementor/class-mfn-elementor.php'));

// gdpr

require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/modules/class-mfn-gdpr.php'));

// WooCommerce functions

if (function_exists('is_woocommerce')) {
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/theme-woocommerce.php'));
}

// dashboard

if ( is_admin() ) {

    defined('MFN_DISABLE_LIVE') or define('MFN_DISABLE_LIVE', false);

    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/admin/class-mfn-helper.php'));
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/admin/class-mfn-update.php'));

    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/admin/class-mfn-dashboard.php'));
    $mfn_dashboard = new Mfn_Dashboard();

    if (! isset($theme_disable['demo-data'])) {
        require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/importer/class-mfn-importer.php'));
    }

    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/admin/tgm/class-mfn-tgmpa.php'));

    if (! mfn_is_hosted()) {
        require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/admin/class-mfn-status.php'));
    }

    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/admin/class-mfn-support.php'));
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/admin/class-mfn-changelog.php'));
    require_once(get_theme_file_path('/functions/admin/class-mfn-tools.php'));

    if( ! MFN_DISABLE_LIVE ){
        require_once(get_theme_file_path('/visual-builder/visual-builder.php'));
    }

}

/**
 * @deprecated 21.0.5
 * Below constants are deprecated and will be removed soon
 * Please check if you use these constants in your Child Theme
 */

define('THEME_DIR', get_template_directory());
define('THEME_URI', get_template_directory_uri());

define('THEME_NAME', 'betheme');
define('THEME_VERSION', MFN_THEME_VERSION);

define('LIBS_DIR', get_template_directory() .'/functions');
define('LIBS_URI', get_template_directory() .'/functions');
```

I've changed the name of the child theme so that the site reverts to the default theme, but can't get to the bottom of why the 'active theme is broken. Reverting to default theme' message is up.

Help appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: A white screen of death usually means a 500 error occurred, which can be anything. Check your web servers error log for an error message that can help narrow down the issue.

Comment: enable wp error log in config file

Comment: Thank you, it's apparent that the Betheme update is the issue, and I can't figure out how to fix it.